# Make uppercase in array

Tags: arrays, r, uppercase, capitalize

Use of order
             Apartment       Canada  Toronto
                     38                  37                2042                  37 
    Appartment Building                 Apt 
                     54                 357

can you help for making capital letters for the charcaters in my array?

Comment: Have you considered using a ... loop?

Comment: no but can you give any advice?

Comment: Could you post a `dput(ordered_use)`?

Comment: I posted the dput @Pascal

Comment: I advise you to consider using a loop.  Happy?  :-)

Comment: What exactly do you want to make uppercase?

Comment: Why did you mangle edit made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
names(ordered_use) <-toupper(names(ordered_use))

> ordered_use
         APARTMENT       APARTMENT BLDG  APARTMENT BUILDING      APARTMENT UNIT APPARTMENT BUILDING 
                 38                  37                2042                  37                  54 
                APT 
                357
```